# How to make registration form with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, validation

This is my php registration form. There are something wrong to this code. My code didn't save data to database when I input the data, and it did'nt check if there are same username or email in databases and if i input the password1 != password2, there is 
"Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tugas3\register.php on line 27"
"Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tugas3\register.php on line 28". Help me solve this problem. I'm using XAMPP for my database. My database name is TUGASPPW and table name is Users.

```
<?php
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
$errorName='';
$errorPass='';
$errorEmail='';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password1']) || empty($_POST['password2']) ||  empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $error = "Semua data harus terisi";
}
else    {
    // Define $username and $password
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password1=$_POST['password1'];
    $password2=$_POST['password2'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    // To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password1 = stripslashes($password1);
    $password2 = stripslashes($password2);
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password1 = mysql_real_escape_string($password1);
    $password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($password2);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    // Selecting Database
    $db = mysql_select_db("TugasPPW", $connection);
    $query = ("select * from Users where email='$email' AND username='$username'");
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    $numResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($password1 != $password2){
        $errorPass = "Password yang anda masukkan tidak sama";
    }
    elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) // Validate email address
    {
        $errorEmail =  "Invalid email address please type a valid email!!";
    }
    elseif($numResults>=1){
        $errorName = "Username or email already exsist";
    }

    else{
        mysql_query("insert into users(name,email,password)  values('".$username."','".$email."','".md5($password1)."')");
        header("location: login.php");
    }
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <title>Login Form in PHP with Session</title>
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
<h1>Pendaftaran</h1>
<span><?php echo $error; ?></span>

<div id="login">
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>UserName :</label>
    <input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text"><span><?php echo $errorName; ?></span><br>
    <label>Password :</label>
    <input id="password1" name="password1" placeholder="**********" type="password"><span><?php echo $errorPass; ?></span><br>
    <label>Ulangi Password :</label>
    <input id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="**********" type="password"><span><?php echo $errorPass; ?></span><br>
    <label>Email :</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="yourname@email.com" type="email"><span><?php echo $errorEmail; ?></span><br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Submit ">

</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`

Comment: You can't mix mysql_* and mysqli_* functions. Change everything to use mysqli or pdo functions and get rid of depricated mysql_*.

Comment: You need to change `AND` to `OR` in your `query` so you don't end up with different usernames using the same emailaddress or same username using different emailaddresses.

Answer (score 0):

first of all check your connection you are connecting with mysql and selcteing youur db with mysqli it create problem also you are excuting your query with mysqli so you can not get proper result from there
user mysql for selecting db and excution of query.

```
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'rootpassword';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = "select * from Users where email='$email' AND username='$username";

mysql_select_db('TugasPPW');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    print_r($row);
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
if($password1 != $password2){
        $errorPass = "Password yang anda masukkan tidak sama";
    }
    elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) // Validate email address
    {
        $errorEmail =  "Invalid email address please type a valid email!!";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("!server");
 $db = mysql_select_db("your db",$con) or die("! db");

$sql = "select * from Users where email='$email' AND username='$username'";

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("! query");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($numrows != '')
{
 echo "user exists";
}
 else{ 
 echo "create new user";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your code. Below verify with below code and find out the mistakes.

```
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","test");
    // To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password1 = stripslashes($password1);
    $password2 = stripslashes($password2);
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password1 = mysql_real_escape_string($password1);
    $password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($password2);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    // Selecting Database

    $query = ("select * from users where email='$email' AND name='$username'");
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    $numResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($password1 != $password2){
        $errorPass = "Password yang anda masukkan tidak sama";
    }
    elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) // Validate email address
    {
        $errorEmail =  "Invalid email address please type a valid email!!";
    }
    elseif($numResults>=1){
        $errorName = "Username or email already exsist";
    }

    if($errorPass!=='' || $errorEmail!=='' || $errorName!=='')
    {
        echo "error";
    }
    else{
        mysql_query("insert into users(name,email,password)  values('".$username."','".$email."','".md5($password1)."')");
        header("location: login.php");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

without combing        mixing mysql_* and mysqli_*
change

```
 $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
 $numResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

to

```
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $numResults = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

but better use mysqli or pdo

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PDO connectivity...

```
    <?php
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
$errorName='';
$errorPass='';
$errorEmail='';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password1']) || empty($_POST['password2']) ||  empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $error = "Semua data harus terisi";
    }
    else    {
        /////////// changes -- start - SHAZ ////////////////
        $username=trim($_POST['username']);
        $password1=trim($_POST['password1']);
        $password2=trim($_POST['password2']);
        $email=trim($_POST['email']);
        // Establishing Connection with Server using PDO by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
        $host = "localhost"; 
        $dbname = 'TugasPPW'; 
        $user = "root"; 
        $pass="";
        // Connect to DB
        try {
            $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$pass);
            $connection->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            die ('ERROR : SORRY! Unable to connect with database >>');
        }

        $sltQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email= ? AND username = ?";
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($sltQuery);
        $stmt->bindParam(1,$email);
        $stmt->bindParam(1,$username);
        $stmt->execute();
        // Here to check if record already present
        if($stmt->rowCount()) {
            // Record found in DB
            $error = 'Email/Username already Exists';
        }
        else {
            // no record found in DB
            if($password1 != $password2) {
                $errorPass = "Password yang anda masukkan tidak sama";
            }
            else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) // Validate email address
            {
                $errorEmail =  "Invalid email address please type a valid email!!";
            }
            else if($numResults>=1){
                $errorName = "Username or email already exsist";
            }
            else{
                $password = md5($password1);
                $insQuery = 'INSERT INTO users SET name = ?, email = ?, password = ?';
                $smt = $connection->prepare($insQuery);
                $smt->bindParam(1,$username);
                $smt->bindParam(2,$email);
                $smt->bindParam(3,$password);
                $smt->execute();
                if($smt->rowCount()){
                    //Data Inserted Successfully
                }
                else{
                    // Failed to insert data
                }
                header("location: login.php");
            }
        }    
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <title>Login Form in PHP with Session</title>
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
<h1>Pendaftaran</h1>
<span><?php echo $error; ?></span>

<div id="login">
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>UserName :</label>
    <input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text"><span><?php echo $errorName; ?></span><br>
    <label>Password :</label>
    <input id="password1" name="password1" placeholder="**********" type="password"><span><?php echo $errorPass; ?></span><br>
    <label>Ulangi Password :</label>
    <input id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="**********" type="password"><span><?php echo $errorPass; ?></span><br>
    <label>Email :</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="yourname@email.com" type="email"><span><?php echo $errorEmail; ?></span><br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Submit ">

</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Glen Swift, The above is expected answer, using PDO.